# LinkedIn REST API Company Updates

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

We are currently trying to fetch our company updates via the `LinkedIn REST API`. We have an application that we can use (we also have administrator account). The problem we are currently facing is that in order to build a request to the company updates endpoint we need to have an authenticated user who is administrator of the company. We don`t want to enforce user login in order for them to see the company updates(also they also have to be admins - which is impossible in real life).

The question is - is there a way to use just the application (or authenticate the application to be administrator of the group) in order for us to obtain the company updates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding LinkedIn API doesn't allow us to access the data just by having the APP-ID and secret. you need to have a user authentication and access token to get data. one way around may be to separate the data fetching part from data presentation. the data fetching application can use the API and get the data and dump into a DB and/or exposing a REST End point for your data presentation application to access this data.